# How to find the used gemset and its path of rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, linode

Is there any command to find the applied gemset and it path of an rails application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using RVM, you can use `rvm gemdir` - this will give you the path of the gemset being used by a Rails application.